# Bootstrap 4 Card Header and Form-Control breaks into new Line

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, adminlte

I using Bootstrap 4 and struggling  with the Card Header. if i add serveral buttons they will aligned in one row but if I add a textbox it will always breaks into a new line. Can anyone help me with that case? I would like to have all controls in one line.

[image]

```
<div class="card">
                <section class="card-header">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <h3 class="card-title" style="inline-block">Product List</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button">Action 1</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="button">Action 2</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button">Action 3</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section class="card-body" style="min-height: 300px;">
                    this is a body
                </section>
            </div>
```

Comment: You can use "d-flex" class on the column to make it on 1 row, and use the other flexbox utils classes to align as you wish. Another option is to use "row" wrapper element and "col-*" classes for the elements

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve that issue otherwise. To use a btn-group within an input-group looks smarter then before.

[image]

```
                <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Action Sample</h3>

                    <div class="card-tools">

                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 450px;">
                            <input type="text" name="table_search" class="form-control float-right" placeholder="Search">

                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                                </button>
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <i class="fas fa-wrench"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" x-placement="bottom-end" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(46px, 19px, 0px);">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Action 1</a>
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Action 2</a>                                            
                                        <a class="dropdown-divider"></a>
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">action 3</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                   
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <div class="card-body" style="min-height: 300px;">
                    this is a body
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
```